# CSS get second element by className without JS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want all my headings with the `title` *titanic* To be 20px high. I can accomplish this by applying this css-rule:

```
h1[title="titanic"] {font-size:20px;}
```

Now i want the second heading with that class to be red. If every heading had the same parent (thus in the same div), i could get that done with this:

```
h1[title="titanic"]:nth-of-child {color:red;}
```

However, when my headings are not in the same parent, I don't know how to select the second heading. I want to know the css-rule i would need to color the second heading red in the following example:

```
<h1 title="titanic">heading one</h1>
<span><h1 title="titanic">heading two</h1></span>
```

Comment: Just to warn you... multiple H1 elements are dangerous for your website SEO

Comment: I understand. It's bad practice. The H1 elements were just examples. They could just as easily have been SPAN elements ;). It's to solve a bigger problem i have been having.

Comment: In your HTML code you gave us, you're missing some more examples (and with the classes you mentioned) to show what are all the needed cases

Comment: I just noticed you asked a very similar question not long before this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901978/css-select-second-instance-regardless-of-its-relative-position Any reason you posted this separately? Other than the slight differences in markup, it's pretty much the same question (with the same answer of "it's impossible" as has already been explained in the comments there).

Comment: True, i deleted it. I asked it in a way that was not easy to answer. Hanse i tried again. ;)

Answer (score 3):

CSS doesn't have a way to select the nth element document-wide. You will have to rely on the structure to determine whether or not to select that second `h1`.

For example, you can choose it only when the first `h1` that comes before the `span` is present, like so (ignoring the appropriateness of having an `h1` within a `span` as in your example...):

```
h1[title="titanic"] + span > h1[title="titanic"]
```

Or if you have a set of these, see if the top-level `h1` elements and the `span` elements all share the same parent. If they do, you can use `span:nth-child(2)` to ensure you don't match any of the other `span`s:

```
h1[title="titanic"] + span:nth-child(2) > h1[title="titanic"]
```

If you can't make *any* assumptions about your document structure at all, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Clear. But this only applies to css rules that rely on classes, id or tagNames. With css i have the power to use even more advanced selectors like [href], which would be more suitable for my problem. I want it purely done with CSS.

Comment: @Nicky Smits: Those advanced selectors are part of CSS so the same principle applies. If you update your question with a more accurate example there's a chance I could show you how it's done, but as I've already stated in my answer CSS alone won't get you very far - you need to look at your markup.

Comment: I changed the title. I need it to work with CSS, and without JS.

Comment: This wouldn't work, because querySelectorAll returns a static nodeList , so i can not set any values directly. And besides that, it again uses JS, and i want it to be with css.

Comment: So would you rather I just said "there is no solution"? Because there isn't any. (Actually, I did already say that - in the very first sentence of my answer.)

Comment: If you don't know a solution you don't have to tell me, because i don't know it either. But even though i like the help, these are not answers that solve the problem..

Comment: No, I'm saying that there *is no* pure CSS solution. There's a difference between not knowing if there's a solution to a problem, and *knowing* that there *isn't* any, and so for that reason my answer stands. [Whether or not you want to accept this is up to you](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it_is_what_it_is), because it is your question after all, but I'm sure there are others out there who would appreciate having a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is with JS. **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/neyeguho/6/edit)**

- Get all your selectors in the document,
- Apply a class or set a *style* to the desired *index one*

```
 var titanic = document.querySelectorAll('[title="titanic"]');
 titanic[1].style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: "Now i want the second heading with that class to be red. If every heading had the same parent (thus in the same div), i could get that done with this: [code]"

Comment: Nice example. There is just 1 small problem. If i would have 8 headings with the title titanic, 4 of them would be coloured red.

Comment: @NickySmits than should this help? `[title="titanic"]:nth-child(1) + * >[title="titanic"]:nth-child(1) {color:red;}` http://jsbin.com/neyeguho/2/edit

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Nice addition. It's just not precise enough yet. If i would have <span><h1 title="titanic">heading one</h1><h1 title="titanic">heading two</h1></span>, it should make the second heading red as wel..

Comment: In your example i see two red headings.

Comment: @NickySmits So ? That's what you asked... your question seems more complicated than it seemed at first. Sorry. Perhaps you should've mentioned *what you don't want* also

Comment: Im sorry if i have been unclear. I want the second heading with the title Titanic to be red. No matter how many there are on the web page. Just the second heading that meets the criterium.

Comment: If you only want the 2nd to be red, won't my answer help you with that? It only targets the second titanic *title* and stops ignoring all others no matter how they are placed.

Comment: @NickySmits Tryed every possible combination of `nth-of-type`, `nth-child`, `(-n+X)`, `(nX)` ... at the end your only way is by doing it with JS. Edited my answer.